# Element of Associative array returning NULL when accessed by key even though a value exists

Tags: php

This is such a weird one, that I'm just not sure what's going on.

I have an associative array stored in a variable called `$suppliers`.

This is a slightly cleaned up `var_dump( $suppliers )`:

```
   array(2) {
       array(4) {
          ["﻿Company"]=>
          string(9) "Microsoft"
          ["Website"]=>
          string(20) "http://microsoft.com"
          ["Brands"]=> ...
          ["Contacts"]=> ...
        }
        array(4) {
          ["﻿Company"]=>
          string(6) "Google"
          ["Website"]=>
          string(17) "http://google.com"
          ["Brands"]=> ...
          ["Contacts"]=> ...
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to access the Company element in a foreach loop like so:

```
foreach( $suppliers as $supplier ):
        var_dump( $supplier['Company'] );
endforeach;
```

But I'm getting NULL for this value every time. All other values can be accessed from within the loop:

```
foreach( $suppliers as $supplier ):
        var_dump( $supplier['Company'] );
        var_dump( $supplier['Website'] );
endforeach;
```

Returns:

```
NULL
string(20) "http://microsoft.com"
NULL
string(17) "http://google.com"
```

I've checked for invisible characters, character encoding issues, and nothing seems to work for directly outputting the value of the Company element.

If I do:

```
foreach( $suppliers as $supplier ):
    foreach( $supplier as $key => $value ):
        var_dump( $supplier[$key] );
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

I'm able to output the "Company" element, but that's the only way it will work.

Any thoughts? Is there something other than an invisible character or encoding issue in the element key that could cause an issue like this?

Comment: Try doing `echo var_dump($suppliers[0]['Company']);` to see if it returns anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Company"] appears to have a bad character in it.

You can modify your code to the following in order to confirm that there is a bad character:

```
foreach( $suppliers as $supplier ):
    foreach( $supplier as $key => $value ):
        var_dump( htmlentities($key) );
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

This returns the following for me:

```
string(28) "ï»¿Company"
string(7) "Website"
string(6) "Brands"
string(8) "Contacts"
```

Comment: A ha! Thank you! I was relying on my IDE's show invisible characters to check if there was something I wasn't seeing, but you're totally right.